# CodeIgniter and Javascript url-rewriting clash

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My project is setup in CodeIgniter. To cleanup CI's url I added a RewriteRule to the htaccess of the page which removes the ugly 'index.php':

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

This rule rewrites:

```
https://baseurl/index.php
```

to

```
https://baseurl/
```

Now, 
I also want to use javascript deeplinking, because the project relies heavily on Ajax page refreshes. The deeplink looks like this:

```
https://baseurl/#/deeplink
```

Problem is: The rewrite rule deletes my beatifully injected deeplink and redirects the user to the root site...
How can i get rid of the index.php without deleting my deeplink on a hard page refresh?

Thanks!

Dave Timmerman

Comment: Have you tried the htaccess recommended by the CodeIgniter docs? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html I'm unable to test it right now, but I imagine it would solve your problem...

Comment: Weirdly enough, those rewrite rules don't work at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment `#/deeplink` is never sent to the server, URL fragments are kept around only on the client's end (the browser). It's never sent to the server as part of the request. The request:

```
https://baseurl/#/deeplink
```

Looks no different to the `index.php` script than:

```
https://baseurl/
```

Not sure how you were ever able to read the fragment on the server to begin with.

Comment: I see. Than URL rewriting and Jquery deeplinking don't really go together i guess... Any other suggestions would be welcome.